# Printing to a local network from a cloud based application, without using a VPN

Tags: cloud, printing

I need to be able to print to network printers on a LAN from a cloud based web application, without using a VPN.

This network is firewalled and the servers are Windows servers.

If I could use a VPN then this would be fairly easy.

Whats the best and/or easiest way to achieve a robust solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A commercial solution could be used:
You could use the [Ricoh Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) printer software and set it as your default printer.
Next you configure your P&S profiles and channels to the desired printers (optionally use automatic profile recognition, so that it selects the correct profile (and printers) based on the content of the document).

Via the web application you only print to the single default printer.

If a commercial solution is not an option, then maybe VPN would be ok.